# App rejected due to vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: android, security, google-play, google-play-console, android-security

I check code one activity can be open from other app its my launcher Activity

I put all other activities as **exported as false**

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="app-host"
                    android:path="/updates"
                    android:scheme="c-deeplink" />

                <data
                    android:host="app-host"
                    android:path="/claim"
                    android:scheme="o-deeplink" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:exported="false"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
           
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ImageCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

```
My app gradle dependencies
```

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
        implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    
        // root beer to check is rooted
        implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.8'
    
        //facebook analytics
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.8.0'
    
        // payments
        implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.3'
    
        // network calls
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    
        // skeleton
        implementation 'com.omjoonkim.library:skeleton-loading-view:0.1.3'
    
        // tasks java-rx android
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
    
        //json factory
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    
        // google
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    
    
    
        //exoplayer
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.11.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.11.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.9.2'
    
        // fire-base
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.8'
    
    
        // image loading
        implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
        implementation 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:2.1.2'
    
        // sdp
        implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    
        //ssp
        implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    
        // graphs
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    
        // custom views
        implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    
        //compression for images
        implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    
        //image crop
        implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3'
    
    
        // (Java Work Manager)
        implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4"
    
        //MixPanel
        implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'
        implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1.2'
    
        //CleverTap
        implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:4.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.2'
        implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1'
    
    
    
        // Lifecycle components
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
        testImplementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.4.RELEASE'
        //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
        annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
    
        implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0'
    
    
        implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:' + rootProject.archLifecycleVersion;
        annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:' + rootProject.archLifecycleVersion;
    
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    
    //    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
    
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.0"
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0"
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0"
    
        testCompile("android.arch.core:core-testing:2.3.0", {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
        })
    
        //In-App Update
        implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.3'
    
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Comment: please attach your manifest

Comment: Your gradle isn't going to be  problem.  It's going to be your intent filters in your manifest.

Comment: davehenry @GabeSechan add manifest

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en Please read the *Additional details*. That's all I can offer to help!